# MySQL Alter Table Copying Structure of Another Table

Tags: mysql

I have a Dev database called db_dev and a live database call db1. In my dev environment I have a table called stores with the following structure:

```
--------------------------------------
| ID | name | address | city | state |
--------------------------------------
```

I then update the table with the following:

```
alter table db_dev.store add country varchar(2);
```

resulting in the following:

```
------------------------------------------------
| ID | name | address | city | state | country |
------------------------------------------------
```

I then run testing, create various indexes, etc. Once the application is stable I would then like to update the structure changes and new indexes to the production environment. Note: I do not want to transfer any data. How can I update the structure of the db1.stores table to be identical to that of dev_db.stores table and copy all new indexes?

Comment: Use a change management process with source control.

Comment: Why don't you create a new table by empty select from the dev one?

Comment: If the changes are not much, you can maintain change scripts for each change you do on dev database. Else, try [flywaydb.org](flywaydb.org) for database source control and migrations. Recently discovered through SO, not used so far.